# Backslash zero delimiter '\0'

Tags: binary, binaryfiles, delimiter

I have seen `'\0'` to be used as a delimiter in mixed binary files (UTF8 strings + binary data). Could anyone explain what `'\0'` means or point to a good place to study?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It's the null character; more info in this Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Answer (score 20):

The two-character `\0` representation is used in C source code to represent the [NUL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), which is the (single) character with ASCII value 0.

The NUL character is used in C style character strings to indicate where the end of the string is. For example, the string `"Hello"` is encoded as the hex bytes:

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 00
```

In this case, the C compiler automatically adds the `00` byte on the end of any double-quoted string. If you wrote the constant as `"Hello\0"`, then the C compiler would generate:

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 00 00
```

Answer (score 10):

`\0` is shorthand for `\000` which is an octal character escape.  In general, you can shorten any octal escape that isn't followed by an octal digit.  This derives from the original C escape sequences (`\n \r \t \f \v \b \000` where the latter is a character value in octal notation; ANSI added some, and `\v` is somewhat rare these days and many more modern languages don't implement it).